# Codeigniter dropdown pass wrong value to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a dropdown list with 5 options, whenever I click the submit button in the modal, the value posted to the controller is not the one I had selected.

Here is my view code

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="procode" id="procode" >

                <option value="AOC">AOC</option>
                <option value="ATN">ATN</option>
                <option value="AOC">APS</option>
                <option value="ATN">ADS</option>
                <option value="AOC">ATW</option>
                <option value="ATN">ATB</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my ajax code for submiting the data to controller is here

```
var url;
    url = "<?php echo site_url('person/ajax_add_claim')?>";
   $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#formclaim').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {

        if(data.status) 
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            $('#modal_form').removeData(); 

            reload_table();
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
            {
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); 
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); 
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); 
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); 


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); 
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); 

    }
});
```

Comment: there are just two different option values - did you even see that ? ;)

Comment: I haven't seen. Please explain. Help me fix this pls

Comment: for `APS` option value is still `AOC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a silly question to answer. But here you go:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="procode" id="procode" >
            <option value="AOC">AOC</option>
            <option value="ATN">ATN</option>
            <option value="APS">APS</option>
            <option value="ADS">ADS</option>
            <option value="ATW">ATW</option>
            <option value="ATB">ATB</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you notice the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The option in your dropdown contains similar values, that might be the cause of the problem.

```
 <option value="AOC">AOC</option>
 <option value="ATN">ATN</option>
 <option value="AOC">APS</option>
 <option value="ATN">ADS</option>
 <option value="AOC">ATW</option>
 <option value="ATN">ATB</option>
```

- Try replacing the values with some other data. Just to test, whether the code is working or not.
- Show us a bit of controller code to see what and how you are displaying the dropdown data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share your controller function and  reload_table function of Javascript. i think you are  not returning accurate data from Controller function. You should use like this.

```
$drop_downdata = $this->db->function(your db query);
```

/*  you pass this data to view like this create a page with this name dropdown_page.php */

```
 $dropdown_view['page'] = $this->load->view('dropdown_page',array('data'=>$drop_downdata),TRUE);
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($dropdown_view));
```

View Page  dropdown_page.php

```
<?php foreach($data as $value): ?>
  <li><?=$value->column_name?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

you will simple get this Drop down in this way

```
`$("#dropdown_id or class").html(response.page)`.
```

It will show your dropdown according to your request